# Iterate through a specific nested object key

Tags: javascript

There is an object like:

```
props = {
  any: 'thing',
  intro: { content: 'foo' }
}
```

Now I want to loop through a given string representing a *specific* path (`props.intro.content`) in a way to set the deepest value to `undefined`:

```
props.intro.content = undefined
props.intro = undefined
props = undefined
```

So the results by iterating the path given above should output these three objects:

```
{
  any: 'thing',
  intro: { content: undefined }
},
{
  any: 'thing',
  intro: undefined
},
undefined
```

I tried to use split and for loop

```
const array = 'props.intro.content'.split('.')

for (let index = array.length - 1; index > -1; index--) {
  console.log([array.join('.')]) // this returns the flatten path
  array.pop()
}
```

but this doesn't handle the object itself, so I do not get the correct object as output.

Comment: You can't access the variable that refers to an object from the object itself.

Comment: you are looking for [mpath](http://npmjs.com/package/mpath)

Comment: There's also [path-value](https://github.com/vitaly-t/path-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive function that does that. I made the example extra deep to show that it's robust to deep nesting.

The one tricky part is the last one you should get just `undefined` if the path starts with the variables name. You can't get the name of the variable referencing the object you pass into the function, so maybe you can add a boolean parameter that pushes `undefined` to the end of the array, and have the string input start at the first key layer.

```js
const object = {
  any: 'thing',
  intro: { 
    content: {
      lets: {
        go: {
          deeper: 20
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}

function deepDelete (mainObj, locations) {
  const props = locations.split('.')
  const outputs = [];
  
  function recurseDelete(obj, props, mainObj) {
    if (props.length === 0) return
 
    recurseDelete(obj[props[0]], props.slice(1), mainObj)
    obj[props[0]] = undefined
    outputs.push(structuredClone(mainObj))
  }
  recurseDelete(mainObj, props, mainObj);
  return outputs
}

const locations = 'intro.content.lets.go.deeper';
const outputArray = deepDelete(object, locations)
console.log(outputArray)
```

Comment: Thanks. I do get `ReferenceError: structuredClone is not defined`, as I am using node 16.

Comment: Hmm,  then instead of `structuredClone(mainObj)` try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainObj))`

Comment: Can't you use just a spread operator: `outputs.push({...mainObj})`?

Comment: Spread only deep copies one level in, it shallow copies deeper levels. That's also why I made the example extra deep. I originally used Object.assign() which also shallow copies deeper levels, and it doesn't work when you go deeper.